# Why does AsNoTracking is increasing the loading time instead of improving the joins operation on large dataset in LinqToSQL c#?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have a query that takes a left join with a table that contains million of records and could double even in a future. It has started to take around 6-7 seconds to respond. I tried using the `AsNoTracking` but weirdly it increases the load time instead of improving.

```
var res = (from rd in db.RequiredData
    join rdm in db.RequiredDataMapper
        on new { t1 = rd.Id } equals new { t1 = rdm.Id } 
    into rd_rdm
    from rdm in rd_rdm.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where (rdm.Name == null || rdm.Name == nameof(Name))
        && (model.TypeId == 0 || rdm.Id == model.STypeId)
        && (ApplicationType.ToLower() != "QR".ToLower() ?
            rdm.ATypes.TypeName.ToLower() != "QR".ToLower() : 1 == 1)
                select rd)
                .OrderByDescending(s => s.date)
                .AsNoTracking();
```

Now, I have narrowed it down as much as I could and after going through articles I found out that `AsNoTracking()` would fast it up but it has increased it's load time even more. What other options I have?

`RequiredDataMapper` table is a bridge table to maintain many to many relationships between `RequiredData` and `RequiredDataMapper`.

Comment: Which EF version is this? Also, use navigation properties instead of joins. Not that performance will be better but it's easier and less error-prone in querying. Another thing (affecting performance) is that you should avoid calls like `rdm.ATypes.TypeName.ToLower()`. If the database collation isn't case sensitive (default in databases like SQL Server) it isn't even necessary. Yet another thing: add the predicate on `rdm.ATypes.TypeName` conditionally: remove `ApplicationType.ToLower() != "QR".ToLower()` from the query.

Comment: @GertArnold: hi, i did what you suggested and tried it in plan sql and tried to see executionplan. The cost is 81% for SORTING operation and 16% for INNER JOIN HASH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do if I were you. I'm assuming you're using SQL.

1 - I would get the raw version of the query like Select *

2 - I would run this on MSSQL and see if it takes really long.

3 - If it takes a long time, if it is not a problem to read dirty data, I would apply WITH(NOLOCK) It is a bit difficult to implement in Ef core. You have to consider it as Isolation level.

4 - I would look at the execution plan of the query. Where the data comes from is bottlenecked. Accordingly, I would switch to indexing operations. In general, the execution plan warns you if there is a missing index and gives an example script.

5 - If there is no problem with what I have counted so far, the indexes used while the query is coming may be fragmented. You can have the index rebuilt by Rebuild or Reorganize.

Comment: hi, thakns for your reply but I have done this, all of it still it doesn't :(

Comment: It must be getting into a bottleneck somewhere. Or the data has grown now, no matter what you do, it will not go down :D

Comment: @progamer If you did all of that, what did the execution plan reveal? Bayram: `WITH(NOLOCK)` is bad advice. Most people don't understand its side effects. If they do, they think twice (thrice...) before applying it.

Comment: Why is it bad advice, it can be used if reading dirty data is not a problem for the client. This is actually a situation related to the place you serve or the criticality of the data. The worst thing is to read the data live.

Comment: @GertArnold: hi, i did what you suggested and tried it in plan sql and tried to see executionplan. The cost is 81% for SORTING operation and 16% for INN JOIN HASH.

Comment: Can you share the full version of the SQL query and the result of the execution plan as XML?

Comment: solved. I made a non-clustered indexes out of the fields used in query. all of them and it's super super fast

Comment: congratulations